Reference for wiki claim about degree of spheres
I have seen the following claim on the wikipedia page for 'vector field' about degree theory on vector fields.

The index is not defined at any non-singular point (i.e., a point
where the vector is non-zero). It is equal to +1 around a source, and
more generally equal to $(−1)^k$ around a saddle that has k contracting
dimensions and $n−k$ expanding dimensions.

My understanding here is that the index is defined in terms of homology. I.e. if $z$ is a zero of a vector field $v$ then, by taking a suitably small ball around $z$ we can define a continuous map from $\varphi:\partial B \rightarrow\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ by $\varphi(x)=v(x)/||v(x)||$ where $\partial B$ is the boundary of the ball. Such a mapping can be represented as $\tilde{\varphi}:\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^{n-1}, \tilde{\varphi}(z)=z^d$, where $d$ is the degree, or index, of $v$ at $z$.
My question is this. Does anyone have a reference for the claim made about the degree being equal to $(-1)^k$ in this article. I am particularly interested in the case that $n=3, k=2$ - can anyone give an expression for $\varphi$ in the case that the vector field $v$ is defined as $v(x,y,z)=(x,y,-z)$, and explain how it can be converted to $\tilde{\varphi}$?

You mention homology in your post, but I notice that you do not mention exactly how the index is defined in terms of homology. Do you indeeed know how that is done? I ask because if you do know that then the answer isn't difficult. On the other hand there are other purely "differential-topological" answers to your question.

By the way this has nothing to do with our tag homology-sphere, so I've removed that.

I am familiar with the definition of degree in terms of the fundamental class of the highest homology group - is this the definition you mean?

I suggest that you pick up a book on differential topology and learn the concept of degree defined there. It is equivalent to the topological definition (with appropriate hypotheses), but in different situations one of those definitions applies more easily than the other. In the situation of index of isolated singularities of vector fields, the differential topology definition usually is easier to apply.
To focus on self-maps of spheres, consider a smooth map $f : \mathbb S^n \to \mathbb S^n$. To define $\text{deg}(f)$, choose a regular value, meaning a point $q \in \mathbb S^n$ such that for each $p \in f^{-1}(q)$ the derivative $D_p f : T_p \mathbb S^n \to \mathbb T_q S^n$ is invertible (a regular value always exists in this setting, by Sard's Theorem). Since $\mathbb S^n$ is orientable, there is an orientation assigned to the tangent space at each point. To each $p \in f^{-1}(q)$ you then assign a local degree $\text{deg}_p(f) = +1$ or $-1$ depending on whether $D_p f$ preserves or reverses orientation, respectively. Then $\text{deg}(f)$ is given by the formula
$$\text{deg}(f) = \sum_{p \in f^{-1}(q)} \text{deg}_p f
$$
This formula is well-defined, independent of the choice of orientation of $S^n$ and independent of the choice of regular value $q$.
In your example of the function $v : S^2 \to S^2$ given by the formula $v(x,y,z)=(x,y,-z)$, this function is a diffeomorphism and so every point is a regular point and has exactly one pre-image. The calculation is particularly easy if you choose an easy fixed point of the function $v$: choose $p=q=f(p)=(1,0,0)$. The linear map $D_p v$ is given in $y,z$ coordinates by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ which reverses orientation. So, $\text{deg}(v)=-1$.
For a saddle with $k$ contracting directions and $n-k$ expanding directions, the trick to the calculation is: first pick a point on the sphere corresponding to one of the expanding directions, so that point is fixed by the sphere map; then set up a local coordinate system using axes parallel to $n-1$ contracting/expanding directions independent of your chosen direction. Your derivative calculation will be expressed as an $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries being $+1$ or $-1$, and exactly $k$ entries of $-1$. So the degree degree of the sphere map, and the index of the vector field, are both equal to the determinant of this matrix which is $(-1)^k$.

I see, thank you for explaining that!
